# Can a horizontally-vented kitchen exhaust have a downward-facing outlet in a soffit?

Tags: kitchens, vent, exhaust-fan, soffit

Can I vent a kitchen exhaust fan horizontally to an exterior soffit, ending with a downward outlet/cap?  (Or must the outlet be horizontal (through a wall) or upwards (through a roof)?

Comment: If the soffit has vents in it, you likely can't exhaust out the soffit at all.

Comment: Your local authority would have the final word, but the problem with venting out is that the possibly moist air you're venting could get sucked back into the attic, leading to future problems.